Dynamically change the label of an InlinePanel
I have a model with an InlinePanel. Can I change the label that is shown to be a field of the model underneath it, in this case the title of the Artist field, instead of just "Artist 1"?
e.g. in the below example, "Artist 3" would become "Aaron Blommaert" then.

My models look high level like this:
class EditionPage(Page):
    # Fields
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Start date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("End date"))
    
    # Panels
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldRowPanel([FieldPanel("start_date"), FieldPanel("end_date")]),
        # TODO: find way to determine label dynamically
        InlinePanel("artists", heading=_("Artists")),
    ]


class EditionArtist(Orderable):
    # Fields
    edition = ParentalKey(
        "events.EditionPage",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="artists",
    )

    artist = models.ForeignKey(
        ArtistPage,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="editions",
    )

    # Panels
    panels = [
        FieldPanel("edition"),
        FieldPanel("artist"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.artist} @ {self.edition} ({self.date})"


